# jquery toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box">
    <h4 style="padding-left: 11px; padding-top: 15px;">Main title</h4>

    <div class="hideunhide">
        <h5 style="padding-left: 14px;">sub title1</h5>
        <div class="horizontal  controls">

        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 30px" class="slider"></div>       
        <br>
        <br>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 14px;">sub title2</h5>
        <div class="horizontal  controls"></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 30px" class="slider"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h5 style="padding-left: 14px;">sub title3</h5>
        <div class="horizontal  controls"></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 30px" class="slider"></div>     
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When i click one  the  should be toggle(hide/unhide)

i have tried something like this,

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none')
    $('.hideunhide').css('display', 'block')
});
```

But it is not working please help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrY4/

Comment: Where is the toggle function??

Comment: I've had some troubles with JQuery toggle in the past too. Ever since I explicitly add and remove my classes instead.

Comment: which element u want to hide or show?

Comment: i want to hide unhide the full div contents --> <div class ="hideunhide">

Comment: Change `$(this)` to `$('.hideunhide')`. Note that this will do hide/unhide thing but it will happen so fast that we can't understand. Maybe `.animate()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make .box class has to toggle then do like this..

```
$('.box').on('click',function(){

$('.hideunhide').toggle();
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use `toggle()` and he accepted an answer suggesting `toggle()`...

Answer (score 1):

pelase have a look on below url

[Fiddler](//jsfiddle.net/ctrY4/4/)!

```
$(function () {
    $('.box').click(function () {
        $('.hideunhide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By seeing you code, it seems you need to hide the `<h4>` tag. Try below.

```
$('.box h4').click(function(){
     $(".hideunhide").slideToggle();
 });
```

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrY4/3/)

Comment: not <h4> tag. The <div> tag with class name "hideunhide". I want to make it "hide" and "show" (like toggle) whenever i click on <h4> tag

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you hide a .box element, which is a parent of .hideunhide element. So if the parent element is hidden, all it's children are invisibile, regardless of their CSS display value.

You should reorganize your html.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like a toggle for the hideunhide?

Solution if it is a yes:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $('.hideunhide').toggle();
});
```

Created a fiddle for the proposed solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrY4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
   use code something like this :

    $('.box').click(function(){
    $('hideunhide').toggle();
    });

*Before used to this correct your html code.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h4').click(function(){
   $('.hideunhide').fadeOut(1000);
   $('.hideunhide').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

This will hide and unhide `.hideunhide` elements in defined milliseconds interval when you click to `h4`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrY4/2)**